# What's it called that period when you get hit and you start blinking and can't get hurt? (Video Games)

Tags: single-word-requests

When you get hit in a video game, like Mario for example, or any other platform game, you usually start blinking and during that blinking period, you don't get hurt, what is that "period" called? It must have a term...

Answer (score 2):

"Invincibility frames", or "I-frames" if you're hip with the lingo.

"[I]nvincibility frames are the period of time (measured in frames) during which a character cannot be damaged."

Reference from [Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159878/what-is-an-invincibility-frame/159879#159879).

Comment: Try adding this reference: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/159879/135159 and quote a definition